# 9-patch drop shadow disappears when image nears the edge

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using 9-patch to produce drop shadow for a box. If the image width is at 280dp (20dp off the edge of the box), I get a good drop shadow (@315 degrees):

[image]

However, if I make the image touch the box edge, the shadow on the right edge almost disappears:

[image]

Here's my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dropshadow">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/frontimage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="center"
/>
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the 9-patch I'm using:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reduce your top and left black border to 1 px (the stretchable area).

Like so:

[image]

Optionally, you can also reduce the right and bottom black border by some pixels (to introduce some padding).

Like so:

[image]

Optionally, you can add some blank (transparent) space (let's say 4px per side) between the image (shadow included) and the black borders.
This will add some padding.

OR

You can add some padding to your RelativeLayout

Comment: Thanks. Actually I'm trying not to have any padding and would like the image to touch the edge. I've tried your suggestion but the shadow near the image when the image touches the edge is still faint.

Comment: So, I suggest to add some padding only near the shadow (bottom and right). This should give some space (not letting the shadow really touch the window edges). Another idea to experiment with would be to darken the shadow a bit. AND (maybe better?) enlarge the shadow size.

Comment: Do you know why having an image close to the edge would affect shadow clarity?

Comment: Not exactly. But I can guess some weird optical aberration that tends to make a "smoked out" color to vanish near the borders. Or maybe the device display isn't so sharp at the edges. Could be due to the presence of the retroillumination LEDs?