# How to set the shadow of TextView border

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to set a `shadow` for the `TextView` border

```
TextView t = new TextView(getBaseContext());
```

If I implement the below code, it creates a shadow for the text within the `TextView`

```
t.setShadowLayer(1.5f, -1, 1, Color.BLACK);
```

But is there a way to set the shadow for the TextView's border?

Answer (score 1):

The best way/efficient way to do it is through 9patch.. you can do it programatically but it will cost you some speed or lagginess..

there is a good example at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049730/9-patch-drop-shadow-disappears-when-image-nears-the-edge).

Answer (score 1):

To get the shadow effect on the border, you can wrap the TextView in a [CardView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).

Answer (score 1):

I find the best wave to add shadow to my TextView is with:

```
android:elevation="3dp"
```

Only for API 21 or higher tough.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
t.setShadowLayer(1, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
```

Or perhaps this in your layout XML:

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:shadowRadius="2"  
   android:shadowColor="#0000ff"
   android:shadowDx="2"
   android:shadowDy="4" 
   android:id="@+id/EditText01" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: `setShadowLayer` will set the shadow to the text inside `TextView`. Question clearly says that " it creates a shadow for the text within the TextView

`t.setShadowLayer(1.5f, -1, 1, Color.BLACK);`

But is there a way to set the shadow for the TextView's border?"