# How to set shadow border of textview

Tags: android, user-interface, textview, shadow

I want to apply shadow border only UI of the textview at bottom not for text only.
Is it possible? please suggest me.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

`t.setShadowLayer(1, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);`

Or perhaps this in your layout XML:

```
`<TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:shadowRadius="2"  
   android:shadowColor="#0000ff"
   android:shadowDx="2"
   android:shadowDy="4" 
   android:id="@+id/EditText01" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`
```

Comment: This code effected on text of textview but I want to set shadow border of textview not text only. @oblivion

Comment: Then try using 9patch, See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049730/9-patch-drop-shadow-disappears-when-image-nears-the-edge